# Fast Fourier Transform (fft) with Time Associated Data Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, fft

I have data and a time 'value' associated with it (Tx and X).

How can I perform a fast Fourier transform on my data.

Tx is an array I have and X is another array I have. The length of both arrays are of course the same and they are associated by Tx[i] with X[i] , where i goes from 0 to len(X).

How can I perform a fft on such data to ultimately achieve a Power Spectral Density plot frequency against |fft|^2.

Comment: Its simply not possible. You could interpolate to a given frequency maybe, there are also other methods though I guess.

Comment: Are the time values uniformly spaced ?

Comment: no they are not, that is the problem effectively.

Comment: This problem might be better suited for dsp.stackexchange.com  Anybody have enough moderator points to move it?

Answer (score 3):

If the data is not uniformly sampled (i.e. Tx[i]-Tx[i-1] is constant), then you cannot do an FFT on it.

Here's an idea:
If you have a pretty good idea of the bandwidth of the signal, then you could create a resampled version of the DFT basis vectors R.  I.e. the complex sinusoids evaluated at the Tx times.  Then solve the linear system x = A*z: where x is your observation, z is the unknown frequency content of the signal, and A is the resamapled DFT basis. Note that A may not actually be a basis depending on the severity of the non-uniformity.  It will almost certainly not be an orthogonal basis like the DFT.